# Python 3 - Using subprocess module to execute java command line prompt

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I have a java program on my computer that has a command line api.  If navigate to the appropriate folder in a command prompt, I can enter the command

java -cp p2.jar propokertools.cli.RunPQL

to make various poker calculations from a command prompt.  I would like to be able to interact with this program through Python.

I've tried:

```
p = subprocess.check_output(['java', '-cp', 'p2.jar propokertools.cli.RunPQL'], cwd='C:\\Program Files\\PPTOddsOracle\\ui_jar')
```

but get this error:

File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 620, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-cp p2.jar propokertools.cli.RunPQL']' returned non-zero exit status 1

I decided to be less ambitious and just try to figure out how to get Python to return my java version, but

```
p = subprocess.check_output(['java', '-version'])
```

and

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["java", "-version"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdout.read()
```

both returned empty byte strings, so I think I'm doing something very wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `java -version` writes to stderr, not stdout.

Comment: Heyyy... subprocess.Popen(["java", "-version"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate() does indeed return my Java version!  Thanks!

Comment: to merge stdout/stderr: `outtput = subprocess.check_output(['java', '-version'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was missing that 'p2.jar propokertools.cli.RunPQL' needed to be split up into separate arguments.

```
p = subprocess.check_output(['java', '-cp', 'p2.jar', 'propokertools.cli.RunPQL'], cwd='C:\\Program Files\\PPTOddsOracle\\ui_jar')
```

Comment: I have found that you need separate arguments in a list if you have `shell=False` (the default).

Comment: You're right.  This also works: subprocess.check_output('java -cp p2.jar propokertools.cli.RunPQL', cwd='C:\\Program Files\\PPTOddsOracle\\ui_jar',shell=False)

Comment: @cdarke: you don't need it on Windows. Though you could do it for portability.